# How can I delivery private key from server to client safety? [Java]

Tags: java, security, download

I would like to generate an SSH keypair for the client on the server.

My previous design was to use rest API to send the post request(or should I use get?) to the backend, then generate the keypair and return it to frontend. Then create the URL for the private key file with the download.

But seems it might cause some safety issue in this way. I'm not familiar with security, so I actually don't know what security problem might cause, and where it would happen.

I hope I can get some idea for the solution, and any suggestions or explain would be helpful.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it unless ...

- you already have a secure channel over which to send the private key, or
- the client and server already have a shared key or keypair that can be used to create such a channel.

But the good news is that if your server implements HTTPS (or a similar SSL based protocol) and has a proper SSL certificate with a proper root CA, then a channel created by a client to the HTTPS endpoint should be secure.  All you then need is a way for the server to authenticate the client; e.g. an account name + password or a client certificate.  (But that implies a shared secret ... for authenticating the client to the server.)

Generally speaking, solutions to this involve some kind of bootstrapping, starting with a shared secret that is injected "out of band"; e.g. in a boot image, or first-boot injection or a USB stick.

Note that this kind of thing should really be set up by someone who understands security, 'cos the damage caused if you get it wrong could be incalculable.

So ...

> I would like to generate an SSH keypair for the client on the server.

The simple answer is don't do it that way around.  Implement it the other way around.  Generate the keypair on the client side and send the public key to the server.

Comment: Hi Stephen, I really appreciate your suggestion and explanation. That is very clear and makes sense to me. I'm glad that I just learned about HTTPS yesterday so I understood the good news you talked about.  So I wonder if the server implements the https, the user login to with the password and the server keep this session. Now if I provide a simple download on the frontend(like <a> tag download) would that be safe? Or I need to do something else special to make sure this file download is encrypted through the band during transfer?

Comment: If you are using HTTPS, all data passing over the connection is encrypted and secure against 3rd-party eavesdroppers.  (Assuming that the cert is valid and the cert's root CA has not been compromised / subverted, and the cert's private key has not been compromised.   There are caveats on **all** security schemes ...)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!  It's very helpful. I think I need to do some more research about rest with https to make sure the security.